# Capistrano deployment fails after upgrade to Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I have production Rails 3.2.3 application which I use to deploy using capistrano. When I decided to upgrade rails to 3.2.11 i did following steps:

1. changed rails version in Gemfile
2. run "bundle update rails"
3. pushed new gems from vendor/cache, Gemfile and Gemfile.lock
4. run "cap production deploy"

Capistrano now fails with error:

```
  * 2013-01-11 15:58:25 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * 2013-01-11 15:58:25 executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
  * executing "[ -e /home/deploy/projects/otv/shared/assets/manifest.yml ] && cat /home/deploy/projects/otv/shared/assets/manifest.yml || echo"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.99.51"]
    [xxx.xxx.99.51] executing command
    command finished in 28ms
  * executing "cd -- /home/deploy/projects/otv/releases/20130111095812 && export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 && /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp -- /home/deploy/projects/otv/shared/assets/manifest.yml /home/deploy/projects/otv/releases/20130111095812/assets_manifest.yml"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.99.51"]
    [xxx.xxx.99.51] executing command
 ** [out :: xxx.xxx.99.51] cp: cannot stat ‘/home/deploy/projects/otv/shared/assets/manifest.yml’: No such file or directory
    command finished in 18773ms
```

I tried to perform these steps with other project which previously successfully used to be deployed with capistrano with the same result.

My [Gemfile and deploy.rb](https://gist.github.com/4509574)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, I was getting this after updating Capistrano to > 2.14.0:

```
*** [err :: ourapp.net] cp: cannot stat `/home/deploy/www/ourapp/shared/assets/manifest.yml'
*** [err :: ourapp.net] : No such file or directory
```

I think symlinking the assets to the shared dir would fix it, but instead of messing around (gotta get this deploy out), I just downgraded cap back to 2.13.5.

Comment: I'm using capistrano 2.14.2 and seeing this same problem after upgrading to Rails 4.0beta1. Is there any solution without downgrading? - I'm not sure where would I symlink the assets from?

Comment: @RomanGaufman The name of manifest file has been changed to `manifest-a5247d227d9b50f54f7c66dc7e640bca.json` style. You can avoid this error just creating `manifest.yml` by `touch` command on the `/home/deploy/www/ourapp/shared/assets` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

New versions of capistrano now have [some code](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/commit/23452d6390d2ff59240f71966409850a7646320f#L1R49) to handle the shared assets path symlinking.
My `config/deploy.rb` had some code to handle this, and the paths were conflicting with each other.
I just removed this line from it to solve the problem:

```
run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/public/assets #{release_path}/public/assets"
```

Answer (score 0):

did you delete all your assets on your distant server before to upgrade?

Sometimes some old references could cause that kind of issue

Cheers,
Jérémy

Comment: I can't understand how to delete my assets. 


...projectpath/shared/assets folder is empty,
all assets located in ...projectpath/releases/yyyymmddhhmmss/public/assets. 


Also I don't understand how can I delete my Gemfile.lock, should I remove it from the repo because code for deploy is taken from the repo?

Comment: Well,keeping your Gemfile.lock in your repo isn't a good practice, as it's auto generated when executing bundle (install, update..). Did you try to execute the last command directly (executing "cd -- /home/deploy/projects/otv/releases/2[....]) on the current release for instance?!

Comment: cd -- /home/deploy/projects/otv/releases/20130111080236/ && export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 && /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp -- /home/deploy/projects/otv/shared/assets/manifest.yml /home/deploy/projects/otv/releases/20130111080236/assets_manifest.yml leads to an error "cp: cannot stat ‘/home/deploy/projects/otv/shared/assets/manifest.yml’: No such file or directory". And this is normal because in all releases manifest file located in public/assets/ not in shared/assets