# Capistrano TOUCH_ASSETS error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

Recently moved project to another server. Capistrano stoped working. How to find what is wrong?

```
 ** sftp upload #<StringIO:0x00000001b4b5d0> -> /home/xxx/production/TOUCH_ASSETS
    [yyy.xxx.lt] /home/xxx/production/TOUCH_ASSETS
    [yyy.xxx.lt] done
  * sftp upload complete
  * executing "cat /home/xxx/production/TOUCH_ASSETS | while read asset; do touch -cm -- \"$asset\"; done && rm -f -- /home/xxx/production/TOUCH_ASSETS"
    servers: ["yyy.xxx.lt"]
    [yyy.xxx.lt] executing command
    command finished in 593ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

Using RVM and Capistrano 2.14.1

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276278/capistrano-deployment-fails-after-upgrade-to-rails-3-2-11) can solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the same problem, just do **set :rails_env, "production"** instead of **set :rails_env, :production**.